# Ember - Saving sub-menu state

Tags: ember.js

I have a sub menu that appears only when a menu item in the main menu is selected.  What I want to do is save the state of the sub menu so that, when a user selects something in the sub menu, then navigates away in the main menu, that sub menu item should still be selected when they return to the sub menu.  But, I'm not sure how to go about it.  Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/martinp999/Ce5j8/2/

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#/a/f">Main Menu</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>{{#link-to 'a'}}A{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'b'}}B{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'c'}}C{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>           
      </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="a">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#/a/f">Sub Menu A</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>{{#link-to 'f'}}F{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'g'}}G{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'h'}}H{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>           
      </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="b">
B
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="c">
C
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="f">
F
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="g">
G
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="h">
H
</script>

App.Router.map(function () {
this.resource('a', function() {
    this.resource('f');
    this.resource('g');
    this.resource('h');
});
this.resource('b');
this.resource('c');});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transitioning from the `A` route, you can inspect the `transition` object and see where you're going. It is possible to stash the location where you're going (if it is a sub-route of `A`) and then utilize it again in the `redirect` hook of the `AIndexRoute`.

Check out this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahaurw01/Ce5j8/3/

Comment: Looks good in your jsfiddle.  But, for some reason, the exact same code doesn't work locally.  The 'transition' object being passed as an argument to the 'willTransition' action of the Route does not have a handlerInfos property.  So I get a "Cannot call method 'any' of undefined"?  I have double checked my library versions.  I am using jquery 2.0.3, handlebars 1.0.0 and ember 1.0.0-4-g111e097 (which is currently the latest). Any ideas?

Comment: I've also found that `transition.router.currentHandlerInfos` still contains the handlers for (e.g.) `[application,a,g]` at the time that `willTransition` is called after I navigate from `/a/g` to `/b`.  So, I can't use that property to decide whether I should set `savedPath` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I thought that `ember-latest.js` pointed at latest production release, it actually points at the beta of beta - canary.  The transition object does not contain a handlerInfos object in prod or in beta, only in canary.

Comment: [Following a further case of domestic blindness](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3632), I've been pointed at more information.  In a more real-world situation, I needed to get the model passed by the link-to helper from the transition object.  It's found in transition.providedModels (doh!).  Works a treat.